# How can I change pictures by onmouseover like a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`document.getElementById("myImg").src =` (Here I want to write a code to get the id from my picture and replace the SRC with "myImg" id)

What should I do ??

Comment: Is this inside the function called from onmouseover?

Comment: I think you should do it with opacity or display hidden like thing. And you can do it with css animations too.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem your facing? Do you not know what to put after `document.getElementById("myImg").src =` ?

Comment: Yes, But I want to write a code that give the id of the picture which I mouseover it somthin like this

Comment: document.getElementById($(this).id).src

Comment: yes its inside the function

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to get the **id** itself. Why not just get the `src` of the picture you want and assign it to your items `src` : `...byId("myImg").src = ...byId("nextImg").src` ?

Comment: because it is not one picture, it is multiple picture that you let the user to mouseover on one of them. that is why I must get the id of src picture to change it with previous one

Comment: ...byId("nextImg").src -->  instead of "nextImg" I want to write a code to support the mouseover, means when you want to mouseover a picture the mouseover function able to show the picture which just you mouseover it

Comment: Then use: `document.getElementById("myImg").src = this.src;`. `this` being the element your `onmouseover` is called on. Btw I was simply providing an arbitrary example, I know it's not one picture. You don't need to get the `id`, just the `src`.

Comment: when I write this.src code the picture going to change but is not showing the face of pic, do you know whats the problem ?

Comment: Without seeing your code I don't know. I think that your functions is probaly not tied to your object then. Then just place a parameter in your function and pass `this`. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3uefgtn7/

Comment: WooooooooooooooooooooooW Bro thank you very much
this is what I wanted, how did you get that.
what this parameter exactly  do ??

Comment: @KamalMahdavi `this` basically means "this object". I'll add an answer below and explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO UPDATE:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw24whny/8/)

MARKUP:

```
<figure>
    <img data-src-1=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Miley_Cyrus_at_Kids%27_Inaugural_2_cropped_filtered.jpg/640px-Miley_Cyrus_at_Kids%27_Inaugural_2_cropped_filtered.jpg data-src-2=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Miley_Cyrus_2008_MTV_VMA.jpg />
</figure>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function changeBacground () {
       figure.setAttribute("src", figure.getAttribute("data-src-2")); 
       figure.classList.add("hover");
}
function resetBacground (){
       figure.setAttribute("src", figure.getAttribute("data-src-1"));    
       figure.classList.remove("hover");
}

var figure = document.querySelector("img");

figure.setAttribute("src", figure.getAttribute("data-src-1"));

figure.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBacground,false);
figure.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetBacground,false);
```

## [DEMO 1:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw24whny/4/)

```
figure{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

MARKUP:

```
<figure>
    <img/>
</figure>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function changeBacground () {
       figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[1]);              
}
function resetBacground (){
       figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[0]);            
}
var imgSrc = ["http://data1.whicdn.com/images/57500972/thumb.png","http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lijbquQxMy1qztump.png"],
    figure = document.querySelector("img");

figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[0]);
figure.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBacground,false);
figure.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetBacground,false);
```

Update for big IMG using `classList  hover`

```
function changeBacground () {
       figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[1]); 
       figure.classList.add("hover");
}
function resetBacground (){
       figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[0]);    
       figure.classList.remove("hover");
}

var imgSrc = ["http://data1.whicdn.com/images/57500972/thumb.png","http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lijbquQxMy1qztump.png"],
    figure = document.querySelector("img");

figure.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[0]);
figure.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBacground,false);
figure.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetBacground,false);
```

STYLE FOR BIG IMAGE

```
img.hover{
    width:200%;
}
```

## [DEMO 2:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw24whny/6/)

Comment: I dont wanna use hover. I am using multiple image, for example you wanna mouseover on one picture so you can see that in large size in an <img>

Comment: ok check the update using javascript

Comment: these codes are true but I do not want to use ARRAY like imgSrc

Comment: @ Kamal What do you want to use SIR?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to add `onmouseover(this)` on the elements you want. What this does is passes the element that has that event on it. So for example:

```
<img onmouseover="changeImage(this)" src="..." />
```

The `this` returns that `img` element itself. In the same way you get an element by saying `document.getElementById(...)`.

*Note: You can add event handlers in the JavaScript as well, that way you don't have to place them in the HTML of you don't want to.*

Now for the code we just want to change the `src` of our main image to the `src` of the element we scroll over like so:

```
function changeImage(self) {    
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = self.src;
}
```

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3uefgtn7/)**